# Is it possible to use React Select multi with no options/dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I basically want to use react select with no options/dropdown (just like an input field) but use the multi feature available in select

so I figured something like this:

```
<Select
  components={{ DropdownIndicator: () => null }}
  placeholder="Start typing to enter options"
  multi
/>
```

but this just gives me `no options` in the dropdown

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding an `options={[]}` prop, at least we achieve what you say doing that in our UI doing that. Adding some sort of "Add value" button input in the dropdown that enables the `isMulti` and then just passing the empty options.

https://react-select.com/props#prop-types

According to the oficial documentation, it is a valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Select, { components } from "react-select";

const msgStyles = {
  background: "skyblue",
  color: "white",
...
};

const NoOptionsMessage = props => {
  return (
    <components.NoOptionsMessage {...props}>
      <span className="custom-css-class">Empty Record Option Message!</span> 
    </components.NoOptionsMessage>
  );
};

const CustomNoOptionsMessage = () => {
  return (
    <Select
      isClearable
      components={{ NoOptionsMessage }}
      styles={{ noOptionsMessage: base => ({ ...base, ...msgStyles }) }}
      isSearchable
      name="color"
      options={[]}
    />
  );
};
```